# setting Custom claims in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Authentication. And i want to use  custom claims
But actually i didn't get how can i  implement this
i want to authenticate the login user with his company_id details
all my document containing company_id so i want to  give any access for the document only the for the user's company id is equal to the company id is saved in the document.

i found that we can use the custom claims for additional authentication purpose.
its a mobile application

in the mobile, mobile call `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)` and getting the UID

i want to know that how can i set the custom claims?
by decoding the token we can get the a details like this

```
{
 "iss": "",
 "sub": "",
 "aud": "",
 "uid": "920",
 "iat": 1600950391,
 "exp": 1600953991,
 "claims": {
   "company_id": 29,
   "tenant_code": ""
 }
}
```

i want to write  rule over my document

i tried to write this.. but all data missing i login a user having company_id=29 but all record is missing

what is wrong with my rule ?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /irrig_sets/{irrigrecord} {
       allow write : if request.auth.uid != null &&  request.auth.token.claims.company_id == resource.data.company_id;
       allow read: if request.auth.uid != null &&  request.auth.token.claims.company_id == resource.data.company_id;   
     }
    match /{collectionname}/{ranch} {
      allow read, write: if true 
      && collectionname!= "irrig_sets";
    }
    
  }
}
```

i dont know this code i write is perfect or not
i am really stuck with these firebase rules..
what is wrong with my code?
how can i write proper rule

i want to give read and write access for all the records in irrig_week having company_id from the claims?

or any alternative method  exist to achieve this ?

or any other idea to get the a specific id from the request and check the id is equal to company_id from irrig_week and give access to that only company?

Answer (score 1):

Custom claims can't be set directly from your mobile app.  That would be a security hole that allows users to give themselves privileges for things you might not approve.

You're supposed to set custom claims on a secure backend using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  If you don't have a backend, you'll need to set something up, and figure out how best to invoke it from your app.

Comment: thank you for your replay.. but after decode the token i am getting this . so its not avialble in the auth request ? .. i checked the documents ...